# Titanium SDK Install Error fetching Titanium Environment

Tags: installation, titanium

Hi y'all I have to install Titanium SDK for work on a Mac. It's all fine until VSCode (newest version) wants me to install the remaining Titanium Tools (newest version as well) as it won't install the Titanium SDK.

I tried everything Google could advice me to. I even changed the type of executing Skript thingys. Which seams not to be the issue. I deleted the Extension and reinstalled multiple Times and I don't know what to do anymore really. What ever I do i'll get "Error fetching Titanium Environment".

Answer (score 0):

can you run this outside of VSCode please:
`ti info` and check that for errors. After that `ti info --output json` as that is what vscode is using.

Make sure Titanium is install correctly. So `node -v` should be 16 (or higher if you use the latest SDK) and you have `ti -v` with 6.1.1 and `alloy -v` with 2.0.2.
If that isn't the case please run `sudo npm i -g titanium alloy` to update to the latest versions. After that VSCode should find the CLI.

VSCode should of course use this extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tidev.titanium-sdk version 1.1.0

Comment: I've installed titanium 1.1.0 through the VSCode extension and used it's environment autopackage for Android, iOS and node bc I wasn't 100% sure about their requirements at that point. I'll give it a try of checking outside of VSCode.

Comment: just wanted to make sure it is not the old (appc) version of the extension!

Comment: No worries. Ti Info helped me out a lot. For some reason the Version of Node was unsupported and JDK wasn't installed propperly.