# Titanium SDK Install Error fetching Titanium Environment (Mac M3)

Tags: installation, titanium

I had to upgrade my Mac to be able to support the latest version of Xcode. I setup the new M3 Mac from a TimeMachine backup from my Intel Mac.  I haven't been able to get Titanium to work in VS Code on the new M3 Mac.  Whenever VS Code starts, I get the following message that never dismisses:   `Titanium: Fetching environment information`

I came across [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76482342/titanium-sdk-install-error-fetching-titanium-environment) and followed some of the suggestions there but have a different result.

When I run `ti info` I get the following error:

```
ti info
Titanium CLI v6.1.1, SDK v12.2.1.GA, https://titaniumsdk.com
Copyright TiDev, Inc. 4/7/2022-Present. All Rights Reserved.

Want to help? https://tidev.io/donate or https://tidev.io/contribute

 /[LiveView] Error: spawn Unknown system error -86
    at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:420:11)
    at spawn (node:child_process:733:9)
    at run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/node-appc/lib/subprocess.js:48:14)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/node-appc/lib/jdk.js:242:5
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3676:28
    at eachOfArrayLike (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:508:13)
    at eachOf (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:628:16)
    at awaitable (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:212:32)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3675:9
    at awaitable (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:212:32) {
  errno: -86,
  code: 'Unknown system error -86',
  syscall: 'spawn'
}
```

Any suggestions on next things to try and/or review would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried:

- node versions 12, 14, 16, & 18
- downgrading VS Code from the latest to a version from May 2023
- uninstalling, rebooting, reinstalling Titanium
- Currently running VS Code 1.85 for Silicon
- Verified that Xcode is installed, all license agreements Accepted, the iOS Simulator runs and has several simulators available.
- Currently running MacOS 14.3 & Xcode 15.2

Answer (score 1):

Ok, soon after posting my question, I continued to research the issue. Wanted to provide an update for any others that might find it helpful.

I found that [installing Rosetta](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211861) solved the issue.

Once Rosetta was installed, I updated the `sdk-version` in the tiapp.xml file and I was able to compile and run my app in the latest Xcode simulators.

Comment: glad you've got it working! Another way to check would have been to add a console log right above `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/node-appc/lib/subprocess.js:48` and log cmd to see which command it wanted to run.